# Can SegWit block weight be increased without a hard fork?

Tags: segregated-witness, block-weight

I know segwit's block weight is 4MB. Can it be increased without a hard fork? If no, was that option even considered, and is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explicit block weight limit cannot be changed without a hard fork.